# Is there a way to move the unity launcher 'show' edge on multiple monitor setup?

Tags: 11.04, unity, multiple-monitors, configuration

I'm in a situation where my primary monitor is on my right and that is the screen with the Unity launcher. When I fullscreen an app, the edge that actually tiggers the launcher to reappear is on my left, **on the screen that does not have the launcher**.

Is there a way to fix this without moving the unity launcher to my left?

This is under Ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a bug!

The detailed multi-monitor design is being worked out now, for 12.04 LTS. You might want to take a look at the proposed design as soon as a draft is available. Check [design.canonical.com](http://design.canonical.com) for news, or hop into #ubuntu-design to see if a draft is available.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Multi monitor support seems even worse in 11.10, hopefully it be functional in 12.04.

Comment: I'm happy to report that this works a lot better under 12.04.